# Selected Options doesnt display on the field but is sent correctly to backend

Tags: html, angularjs

So i have a project in which i have to display some data from the table. Now i want to change the size of the data based on a field above the table that is actually a select input field and sends a value to the angular controller. Now this is working perfectly except for the fact that the field doesn't show the selected number of data being displayed on the field.
[This is the empty field](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0m89R.png). but the data is inserted correctly. Also on debugging I found another option [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/akxxz.png) on the field that is not in the html code. Here's my code for the html and the controller.

**View:**

```
<li class="manual-dropdown pull-right">
    <select id="ddPageSize" ng-model="PaginationInfo.pageSizeSelected" ng-change="ChangePageSize()"  aria-controls="DepartmentTable" class="form-control pull-right">
      <option value="5">5</option>
      <option value="10">10</option>
      <option value="25">25</option>
      <option value="50">50</option>
      <option value="-1">All</option>
    </select>
  </li>
```

**Controller:**

```
$scope.PaginationInfo = {
    maxSize: 5,     // Limit number for pagination display number.  
    totalCount: 0,  // Total number of items in all pages. initialize as a zero  
    pageIndex: 1,   // Current page number. First page is 1.  
    pageSizeSelected: 5, // Maximum number of items per page.
}

GetData(searched);

function GetData(searched) {
    //debugger
    //var noOfPages = 1;
    var SearchData = $scope.StatusSearch.Search;
    if (SearchData == "") {
        searched = false;
    }
    var Displaysize = $scope.PaginationInfo.pageSizeSelected;
    var index = $scope.PaginationInfo.pageIndex;
    if (searched == false) {
        Get("/User/GetData?Size=" + Displaysize + "&index=" + index, false).then(function (d) {
            //$("#").val()
            //$scope.userAccount.CountryID = $("#ddCountryOptions").val();
            // $scope.PaginationInfo.maxSize = d.info.maxSize;
            $scope.PaginationInfo.totalCount = d.totalSize;
            $scope.PaginationInfo.pageIndex = d.index;
            $scope.PaginationInfo.pageSizeSelected = d.size;
            //$scope.noOfPages = $scope.PaginationInfo.totalCount / $scope.PaginationInfo.pageSizeSelected;
            $scope.accountlist = d.GetList;
            $scope.$apply();
        })
    }
    else {
        // alert($scope.SearchData.Search);
        Get("/User/SearchData?inputstring="+ SearchData, false).then(function (d) {
            $scope.accountlist = d.GetList;
            $scope.PaginationInfo.pageIndex = index;
            $scope.PaginationInfo.pageSizeSelected = Displaysize;
            $scope.PaginationInfo.totalCount = d.totalSize;
            $scope.$apply();
        });
    }
}
```

**explanation for the Controller**: The data is loaded on page load so the GetData() function is called immediately. the default page size is set to 5 as shown and when i make a change to the field i recall the GetData() function with page size as a argument and the back end does the rest and returns a amount of data that i asked for. Also the reason there are 2 ajax calls in this function is to implement a search function. which check if the input field is empty or has a value and based on that  output the data.

What i want to know is why is the page size field on my dropdown empty when i select a value.

**Edit:**
After a bit more research i found that the ng-Model is making a empty option with the value of the option i selected. Now the problem still remains i don't know how to display the value in the empty object. if i do select another option as selected, my ng-model value does not change. So i am still stuck with this. Also i have already give the ng-model an default value of 5 the same as my first dropdown option. so in case i tag any other option as selected, the ng-model option will remain 5 no matter how many times i change the dropdown value.

Comment: What does your ChangePageSize() function do?

Comment: right after `</select>` print your `pageSizeSelected` like `{{paginationInfo.pageSizeSelected}}`. I have tested your list, it shows perfectly fine, there must be something wrong with your `CallBack`, try printing `d.size` too and also assuming that `ChangePageSize()` just calls the `GetData()`

Comment: @NTP it changes the size of the data and recalls the GetData() with new size as the parameter

Comment: @Shaheryar.Akram I will check and yes ChangePageSize() only calls GetData()

Comment: @Shaheryar.Akram  i checked the pageSizeSelected and it displays the value i am selecting in the dropdown. and the rest of it is also working fine. I did a little more reseach and found that the ng-model is creating an empty option with the value i selected as shown in the 2nd picture link in my question. it will change the value when i select another option but the field remains empty, because that empty object is selected by default. and if i place selected on any of the other options the value of the mg-model will become constant and wont change.

Comment: umm... try using `ng-value="5"`  instead of  `value="5"`

Comment: I solved it for now but i will try this later and let you know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright i kind of solved my issue, though I am not sure if this is a good way to do it.

So what i did is simply bind the pageSizeSelected Value to the html select element by id.

```
     $("#ddPageSize").val(d.size)
     $scope.pageSizeSelected = $("#ddPageSize").val();
```

before $scope.$apply and it worked. Now when i select a value from the field it changes and displays the value i selected.